# Rotate navigation bar button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation, uinavigationbar

I want to rotate navigation bar button image by 45 degree. I used the following code to do this

```
    CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(3.141/2));
    [self.button setTransform:cgaRotateHr];
```

It is working fine for other button images, but not working for navigation bar button. I dont understand what is the cause of this unexpected behavior. Any help is greatly appreciated ....

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of `UIView`...

Answer (score 1):

try this code to create new bar button item, then set it to left/right of navigation bar

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barItemWithImage:(UIImage *)img size:(CGSize)size target:(id)target action:(SEL)selector
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);

    [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // your transform code
    CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(3.141/2));
    [button setTransform:cgaRotateHr];

    UIBarButtonItem *forward = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];

    return forward;
}
```

Comment: this is the method that I am using now and able to rotate, but rotation is not happening as expected....

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in following way...

- Drag and drop an `UIView` at Bar button item.
- Drag and drop `UIButton` on this view.
- Then code to rotate,

  ```
  CGAffineTransform cgaRotateHr = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(3.141/4));
  [self.button setTransform:cgaRotateHr];
  ```